# ivs chat websocket connect failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, chat, amazon-ivs

I followed the instructions to create a chatroom and token, and used the sample code to connect to the chatroom using WebSocket, but I got a connection error.

my lab is hosting a sample file ivs-chatroom.html on my ec2 server. And tried to connect to wss://edge.ivschat.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com failed.

```
const chatClientToken = "AQICAHgDPFqoWS2jdOfTGB1Vo7NQnk0RhxoHKwei87S3M72_WgGXpV-mDgAwwUJ2UdCY15ZUAAAB0TCCAc0GCSqGSIb3DQEHBqCCAb4wggG6AgEAMIIBswYJKoZIhvcNAQcBMB4GCWCGSAFlAwQBLjARBAyJQR2ruBPj-WXSeyACARCAggGE1gSj19XcIQPV30V8wF15YmAk7Rac086esruMblXDKabrTC2UdanFCksa4aE62SeppjmhKleGNSvXUH0IajebRu4FvsflOgldfAEto8Kmum_--y7JnM0pRiefk03tXpFI9mXGhQ0AY8sbsw1gZIeg4xttXq7umQKEYef3bpsD-nC_pEcFyFPz6ilkNPVjZNaPRK_jBikhvyVImCh7x1PT3LGa8j8xhKtzGZdY1LzNgnbS9x8Q7rNmeekhkZtOaI04sMsxVIHRJlT9fGvdpkeompQo_IbUU_-Kf4YhIEROSnRSH1qSzOztUmjD33K18L5xmFnorgYCM_CsNydLMuxv8s2ygFJeOiJ-_J358y1Qmr6AdMZT-xI7lBhVftubxQ-LAwL3Hs-NPqIlq079MbH4xw1YmH8yJ56V28AKl0NfVavMWMhfwRepr2BiSUd6gQyE6rB2Y2MbQp3c4C-gMvlMAwPYMBesbTb9kCQQP-Qz2Qz5L4ZsLgJZ04kvlSVXqezFxOoNDQ!!#0";
const socket = "wss://edge.ivschat.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com"; // Replace “us-west-2” with supported region of choice.
const connection = new WebSocket(socket, chatClientToken);

/*
2. You can send your first message by listening to user input 
in the UI and sending messages to the WebSocket connection.
*/
const payload = {
  "Action": "SEND_MESSAGE",
  "Content": "text message",
  "Attributes": {
    "CustomMetadata": "test metadata"
  }
}
connection.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
```

[error console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZCNI.png)